# Matplotlib multiple colorbars appearing in subplot animation

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation

I have two contour plots - the first is static and should just be in the background, the second I'm animating with transparency over the top. I'd like a static colorbar for the top (dynamic) set of data. I've tried to adapt some code for an example I saw with just one ax, but I keep getting a new colorbar appearing at each step of the animation. I can see why this is (the `plt.colorbar` I'm calling each time) but I'm not sure how else to add the colorbar to the data.

The code below is some example data I've just made up to give the idea.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation

size = 200
x = np.arange(0, size, 1)
y = np.arange(0, size, 1)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

# Define example data
data1 = np.exp(-((X-100)**2 + (Y-100)**2)/20**2)
data2 = np.zeros((10, size, size))
for i in range(10):
    data2[i,:,:] = np.exp(-((X-100+i)**2 + (Y-100+i)**2)/20**2)

def plotfunction(data_k, k):
    ax2.clear()
    colors = ax2.contourf(data_k, alpha = 0.5)
    plt.colorbar(colors)
    return ax2

def animate(k):
    plotfunction(data2[k], k)

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(111, facecolor = "none")
ax1.set_aspect('equal')
ax2.set_aspect('equal')

ax1.contourf(data1)

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames = 10)
anim.save("thing.gif")
```

[image: Graphs]

Comment: you create a colorbar every time `animation` calls `plotfunction`

Comment: I know, although I'm not sure how to create a colorbar for that axis in a way that doesn't make that happen